# how to increment a cron expression

Tags: cron

I have a starting point for a cron schedule and I want to create a new cron expression after a specified time interval.

For example, I start with a cron expression for 1 job as "0 0 12 * * ?"

I need to create a second cron expression for a second job with an interval of, let's say, 30 mins. So it becomes: "0 30 12 * * ?"
Like that, I want to keep incrementing and create multiple cron schedules for different jobs.

So,

```
1st job - "0 0 12 * * ?"
2nd job - "0 30 12 * * ?"
3rd job - "0 0 13 * * ?"
4th job - "0 30 13 * * ?"
.
.
.
```

Is there something like: `(cron expression 1) + 30mins = another cron expression` ?

Comment: easy answer:no
you would need to write a script and that would need to under stand time to allow for cross day boundaries.
I suggested you write a script that writes out all the times(in the normal HH:MM format) and then write another script to parse out the results into the cron format.

Comment: Maybe you are approaching the task wrong, please explain what you are trying to achieve, another tool may exist. Like at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-job-scheduling/index.html#N10181